# Puppet Server Scaling CA

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

With Puppet 3.x it was possible to split out the CA into a seperate server and then have each of the other Puppet masters proxy certificate requests to the CA. Is this approach still possible with puppetserver 2.6?

I can't seem to find anything in the documentation about this.